# как покрасить ввод?

Tags: python

Как покрасить input в python? (при помощи colorama либо termcolor)

print краситься отлично

```py
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()

print(Fore.RED + 'test')
```

но если провернуть такое с input он не покрасится

```py
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()

input(Fore.RED + 'test')
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(Fore.RED + 'test')
input()
```

Comment: Желательно, чтобы не было различий с исходными требованиями, использовать `print(Fore.RED + 'test', end='')`. Так после выполнения функции не будет переброса на новую строку